# Android custom dialog doesn't fill parent in large devices

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

I have this layout for custom dialog, this works fine for normal and small devices, but in case of large devices it's width doesn't fit to width (fill parent) but I can manually give it some value in dp to achieve the size I want. I want to know why isn't fill parent  working by default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f70000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewInvoice"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonPrint"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buttonPrint" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buttonCancel" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try replace fill_parent by match_parent

Comment: that dosen't work either

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout lay = new RelativeLayout(YourActivity.this);
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout,
            lay);
    dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
    window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this . It may help you

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp1 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

                lp1.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;// change this option to your convienience
                lp1.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                Your dailog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp1);
```

Comment: that's not the point, If I have to go for changes in activity class then also I can hardcode the required dp value in xml file. But the question is still there why isn't filling by default.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is *likely* because of the Window that contains the View. It does not have the take up the full width by default as Dialogs don't do this normally. You must explicitly set the window to take up the fullwidth; which would affect the calculation before the view is drawn. Which SHOULD be called before the show().

Keep in mind that when you call show is when the Layout of the content within the window will begin getting drawn.